# Bluesnap Chargeback Webhooks/IPN

Tags: webhooks, bluesnap

I took a quick look at the IPN types and parameters associated with Bluesnap webhooks - https://support.bluesnap.com/v2.2.7/docs/ipn-parameter-reference

Is there an IPN that gets sent when a Chargeback is won by the merchant? I see Chargeback IPN being sent when a chargeback is issued.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by saying "when a Chargeback is won by the merchant"?

Chargeback, by definition, is initiated by the issuing bank:

> "...the return of funds to a consumer..., forcibly initiated by the
>   issuing bank of the instrument used by a consumer to settle a debt."